# virt-manager: Can't make a sparc64 vm

Tags: linux, ubuntu, qemu, libvirt, virt-manager

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3
virt-manager version: 2.2.1

Whenever I go to make a sparc64 vm I get this error message

```
Unable to complete install: 'internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2021-10-15T02:48:09.558938Z qemu-system-sparc64: -device piix3-usb-uhci,id=usb,bus=pci,addr=0x2: PCI: slot 2 function 0 not available for piix3-usb-uhci, reserved'
```

I cannot remove this USB Controller device, if I right click on the controller and remove it, it instantly respawns. If I remove the XML entries of this USB Controller on overview or on the device itself it also instantly respawns. If i try changing the address, slot, or function it gives the same error message or one that says "in use by pbm-bridge".

Yes I have installed qemu-system-sparc, yes I have installed openbios-sparc, yes the only way I got this to work is using qemu with no virt-manager involved but I'd like using virt-manager for easy use and access. I also have no idea how to modify this with virsh since when I list the virtual machines I get nothing even though there are 2 vms in virt-manager.

I have tried googling for this too to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bug in libvirt's PCI address assignment logic for sparc64. Unfortunately this is not entirely surprising since sparc64 gets very little attention from anyone these days, so isn't well tested. I'd encourage you to report the issue to libvirt's upstream bug tracker.

Comment: Alright, will do that when I have the chance to do so.